# Syntax error caused by using different version of IDL

Tags: idl-programming-language

I am new in IDL. When I use IDL version 8, my program run successfully. But when I use IDL Version 7.1 I get a syntax error that you can see below.

How can I fix this issue?

*IDL> .com schwmodfirstiter_box.pro*

```
   str +=pars[i].name+strn(p[i],format='('+pars[i].sformat+')')
                                       ^
  % Syntax error.
 At: /home/behzad/schwmodfirstiter_box.pro, Line 5
 % 1 Compilation error(s) in module SCHMAKEPARSTRING.

    str +=pars[i].name+strn(p[i],format='('+pars[i].sformat+')')
                                        ^
% Syntax error.
 At: /home/behzad/schwmodfirstiter_box.pro, Line 14
% 1 Compilation error(s) in module SCHMAKEPARSTRING0.

  mlstr=pars[0].name+strn(ml[k],format='('+pars[0].sformat+')')+'/'
                                    ^
       % Syntax error.
          At: /home/behzad/schwmodfirstiter_box.pro, Line 63
          % 1 Compilation error(s) in module SCHMAKEMODEL.
          % Compiled module: SUBMITORBLIB.
          % Compiled module: COMPILENNLS.
          % Compiled module: SCHWMODFIRSTITER.
```

IDL> 
% Interrupt encountered.

Comment: What does the `strn` function do?

Comment: Hi, this is strn code (https://idlastro.gsfc.nasa.gov/ftp/pro/misc/strn.pro)

Answer (score 0):

strn.pro is not part of IDL but is likely from 
https://idlastro.gsfc.nasa.gov/ftp/pro/misc/strn.pro

Make sure you have this procedure in your !Path and can compile it.

Comment: I really appreciate you for your answer, :) I will do it .